# Div auto-increment page for gallery

Tags: php, javascript, html

i want create a script auto-increment div number every time reach the limit 16 pics.
With "next" - "prev" controls.

example:
if i have 16 pics in database, these remain in page N.1, but if i've 20 pics: 16 pics in page N.1 and 4 pics in page N.2 ...etc

The number of page it depends from the number of the pics in database sql.

Javascript or PHP?

Thank's!

Comment: Have a try and return with any problems. Its not a code writing service I am afraid.

Comment: use `LIMIT` in your queries to limit the returned db rows for that page, other then that we cant help you till you actually have a problem. Try googling `Pagination`

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called pagination.

https://phpacademy.org/course/pagination